# Equivalent definitions Stiefel - Whitney / Chern - classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space, characteristic-classes, grassmannian

There are some details I still don't understand about the definition of Stiefel - Whitney / Chern - classes. Let $\gamma_n^1$ be the tautological line bundle over the real or complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$. For $n\to\infty$ write $\gamma^1$ instead of $\gamma_\infty^1$. There are two common ways to normalize Stiefel - Whintey classes, either require $$w_1(\gamma_1^1)\neq 0\text{ (e.g. Milnor, Stasheff)}\quad\text{or that}\quad w_1(\gamma^1) \text{ generates } H^1(\mathbb{R}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}_2)\text{ (e.g. Hatcher)}$$

Why are these definitions equivalent? Say you use Milnor/Stasheff's definition, then the inclusion $j:\mathbb{R}P^1\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ is covered by a bundle map such that $\gamma_1^1 \cong j^*\gamma_1$ and hence $j^*w_1(\gamma_1) = w_1(\gamma_1^1)\neq 0$ requires $w_1(\gamma_1)\neq 0$ (right?)

Vice versa, Hatcher writes (p.81, Vector bundles and K - theory) "...the inclusion $i:\mathbb{R}P^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ induces an isomorphism $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}_2) \cong H^1(\mathbb{R}P^1;\mathbb{Z}_2)$" and I can't see why this is true.

There is a more general statement that $H^p(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})) \cong H^p(G_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty))$ for all $p<k$ and I know why this is true ( (co)homology of CW - complexes) but it doesn't apply to Hatcher's statement since then $n=k=p=1$.

I appologize if this is something trivial, I am still a beginner with these things. Thanks for any help!

Comment: $1)$ Right. $2)$ If $X$ is a CW complex with $k$-skeleton $X_k$, then the inclusions induce $i)$ an isomorphism $H^nX\xrightarrow{\cong}H^nX_{n+1}$, $ii)$ an injection $H^nX\rightarrow H^nX_n$ (any coefficients). In the case that $X=\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ we get that $H^1\mathbb{R}P^\infty\rightarrow H^1\mathbb{R}P^1$ is injective. Calculating the groups with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients we see that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: They're equivalent because $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}, \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ so it has a single nonzero element.

Comment: @Tyrone I am aware of the equivalent result in homology (there the map induced by the inclusion is a surjection on homology groups), so the corresponding result in cohomology makes sense to me. Thanks, this was what I needed:)